# Deserialise Json to Dictionary<string, object> where object is native value type

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I am trying to deserialise a `Dictionary<string,object>`, but the deserialiser returns a `Dictionary<string, JsonElement>`.

```
    [Fact]
    public void MyTestMethod()
    {
        // Arrange

        var input = @"
        {
            ""Key1"":""Value1"",
            ""Key2"":true
        }";

        // Act
        var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(input)!;

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(typeof(string), obj["Key1"].GetType());
        Assert.Equal(typeof(bool), obj["Key2"].GetType());
    }
```

How do I deserialise into native values?  (I know the dictionary will never have complex sub-objects).

Comment: @Serge This is System.Text.Json

Comment: If you tell the serialiser to use `object`, then it will use it's default type which in this case is `JsonElement`. There's no way for the framework to figure out what type to use. If you need native values, then you need to either write your own custom converter or don't use Dictionary

Comment: @DavidG I understand this is why I advise to forget that it is even existing.

Comment: @Serge But that is like telling someone to not go to the library when they ask how to get to the supermarket. It's confusing.

Comment: @DavidG Sorry, but I don't see any confuse here. OP should know that System.Text.Json can only serialize "Hello world". For something  a little more complicated a software developer should create the custom serializer.

Comment: The only thing you can control in the framework as it is now, is to set `JsonSerializerOptions.UnknownTypeHandling` but that only lets you choose between `JsonElement` and `JsonValue`

Comment: @Serge Saying *System.Text.Json can only serialize "Hello world"* is a gross misrepresentation of what STJ can do, you're only making things worse.

Comment: @DavidG Sorry, but it is just IMHO and in my experience to work with the Json strings. What  usually needs 1 line of code using Newtonsoft.Json , sometimes needs 1 hundred lines of code using STJ

Comment: Your experience is irrelevant to the needs of the OP. Perhaps they have performance needs that require STJ or a company mandate that forces the use of STJ, or even interopting with a library that uses STJ. The advice to "just switch" isn't helpful and unnecessarily distracts from the OP's question.

Comment: This question is weird. I assume the property types might change for every property. So why do you want to deserialize in the first place? Why not just work with `JObject`s and `JsonElement`s if the data is that dynamic?

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you need to use a custom converter. Something like this would work:

```
public class ObjectNativeTypeConverter : JsonConverter<object>
{
    public override object? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, 
        JsonSerializerOptions options) => reader.TokenType switch
        {
            JsonTokenType.True => true,
            JsonTokenType.False => false,
            JsonTokenType.Number when reader.TryGetInt64(out long l) => l,
            JsonTokenType.Number => reader.GetDouble(),
            JsonTokenType.String when reader.TryGetDateTime(out DateTime datetime) => datetime,
            JsonTokenType.String => reader.GetString()!,
            _ => JsonDocument.ParseValue(ref reader).RootElement.Clone()
        };
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // An exercise for you if you need it
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

*(Note: this is taken almost verbatim from the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0#deserialize-inferred-types-to-object-properties))*

And use it like this:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions();
options.Converters.Add(new ObjectNativeTypeConverter());

var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>>(input, options);
```